# How to validate Recaptcha in this case?

Tags: php, recaptcha

my website has both recaptcha v1 and a generic captcha method for validation,
then i decided to upgrade my recaptcha v1 to recaptcha v2
so i placed all files from Google ReCaptcha git and placed on my website.
So captcha is showing now, but every time i click the submit button it shows invalid captcha.

currently user registration form has this code to validate recaptcha

```
if(!$captcha->is_valid()) {
    $_SESSION['error'][] = $language->global->error_message->invalid_captcha;
}
```

and i believe the source of problem is from this part of code

```
  /* Custom valid function for both the normal captcha and the recaptcha */

 function is_valid() {

        if($this->recaptcha) {

             $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($this->recaptcha_private_key);
            $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            return ($response->is_valid);

        } else {

            return ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha']);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
/* Custom valid function for both the normal captcha and the recaptcha */
function is_valid() {

    if($this->recaptcha) {

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($this->recaptcha_private_key);
        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        return ($resp->isSuccess());

    } else {

        return ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha']);

    }
}
```